# Is it possible to call a static function in a virtual function ? ( I got LNK2019 ERR )

Tags: c++, static, virtual, linker-errors, cinder

I'm trying to write a basic static class to Trigonometry utility in c++ for Cinder.

This is my main file:

```
#include "cinder/app/App.h"
#include "cinder/app/RendererGl.h"
#include "cinder/gl/gl.h"

//#include "MyStaticClass.h" //this simple include doesn't work...
#include "C:\Users\ALEX\Cinder Projects\LearnLinkage\vc2013\MyStaticClass.h"// so I have to use this stupid absolut path...

using namespace ci;
using namespace ci::app;
using namespace std;

class LearnLinkageApp : public App {
  public:
    void mouseDown( MouseEvent event ) override;
};

void LearnLinkageApp::mouseDown( MouseEvent event )
{
    MyStaticClass::MyStaticFunction();
}


CINDER_APP( LearnLinkageApp, RendererGl )
```

This is my static class file :

MyStaticClass.h

```
#pragma once
static class MyStaticClass
{
public:
    MyStaticClass();
    ~MyStaticClass();
    static void MyStaticFunction();
};
```

MyStaticClass.cpp

```
#include "MyStaticClass.h"


MyStaticClass::MyStaticClass()
{
}


MyStaticClass::~MyStaticClass()
{
}

static void MyStaticFunction(){

}
```

I've got this message error : 
Error   4   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl MyStaticClass::MyStaticFunction(void)" (?MyStaticFunction@MyStaticClass@@SAXXZ) referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall LearnLinkageApp::mouseDown(class cinder::app::MouseEvent)" (?mouseDown@LearnLinkageApp@@UAEXVMouseEvent@app@cinder@@@Z)  C:\Users\ALEX\Cinder Projects\LearnLinkage\vc2013\LearnLinkageApp.obj   LearnLinkage

I made some researches about this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29
and this 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule

the problem seems to be a static function get unresolved external symbol , can you tell me more about this ? and is it theorically possible to call a static function inside a virtual function in cpp ??

Thanks for your support

Comment: _" and is it theorically possible to call a static function inside a virtual function in cpp ??"_ Sure it is. You're on the wrong track diagnosing your error.

Comment: Yes it is possible. Suspect it is your build instructions giving problems. - Also: why the tag spam, suire you are using "cinder", but it isn't relevant to the bit giving you problems..

Comment: You need to define the member function, not a similarly named free function; the member's full name is `MyStaticClass::MyStaticFunction`.  (And "static" means completely different things when used with a member function and when used with a free function. The details of the differences aren't suited for the comment format.)

Comment: Classes can't really be static, though they may contain static members, and you may declare static instances.

Comment: Thanks everybody for your answers !  The problem was just as molbdnilo explained , it was because I didn't defined my function with the namespace of my static class, so the compiler wasn"t able to link it